# play creates tables with the fields sorted alphabetically

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am using a model in Play like this:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String fullname;
    public boolean isAdmin;

    public User(String email, String password, String fullname) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

}
```

Then, the table created by Play! has fields sorted alphabetically like:

```
id
email
fullname
isAdmin
password
```

Is there any way to have it in the right order?

Comment: what is alphabetical? The rows or the columns? Data in a relational database table has no inherent order unless your query has an `order by` clause (ignoring the concept of clustered indexes)

Comment: If you view your data in let's say phpmyadmin, or any other mysql (or any db) client its very important to view table's columns in the specified order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Play uses Hibernate. Hibernate orders the columns when it creates the tables. See [this discussion](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2386856&sid=197ea475db77dd6015ca8e29f5f311a3#p2386856):

> It is sorted to ensurce deterministic ordering across clusters.

To get a different order, let Hibernate create the DDLs for the tables and sort the columns the way you like.

That is: Don't let Play/Hibernate create the tables automatically. Instead, create them manually.

Comment: I feel the strong need to point out that in a relational database there is really no need to ever worry about the "order" of columns in a table

Comment: Wow! you 're fast. Thank you very match!